# Working through summations to show equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, summation-method

Given

equation 1:
$$E = \sum_{k=1}^N \tau x_k g(\frac{n_k}{\tau}) + \sum_{k=1}^N n_kh(\frac{n_k}{\tau})$$

equation 2:
 $$E =   \frac{1}{2}\gamma X^2 + \epsilon \sum_{k=1}^N |n_k| +\frac{\eta*}{\tau}\sum_{k=1}^N n_k^2        $$  where $$\eta* = \eta - \frac{1}{2}\gamma\tau$$

I am told that $n_k = \frac{X}{N}$   and $x_k = (N-k)\frac{X}{N}$ and $k = 1,...,N$

and that from equation 1 and 2 and the above definitions

point 1:
$$E = \frac{1}{2}XTg(\frac{X}{T})(1-\frac{1}{N}) + Xh(\frac{X}{T})$$

point 2: 
$$E = \frac{1}{2}\gamma X^2+\epsilon X + (\eta - \frac{1}{2}\gamma\tau) \frac{X^2}{T }$$

note here $\tau$ is a time variablce

Can you show how to get to point 1 and point 2 from  equations 1 and 2?

Thank you

Comment: In your question you mix up the letters $T= \tau$. Further point1 and point2 don't look correct to me, are you sure that they are right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that $T:=\tau N$.

Since $n_k$ is free of $k$, you are summing $N$ copies of the same thing in the second summation of equation 1, yielding $$N\cdot{\frac XN}\cdot h\left(\frac X{\tau N}\right)=X h\left(\frac XT\right).$$

As for the first summation in equation 1, we can substitute $x_k:=(N-k)\frac XN$ and $n_k:=\frac XN$, then pull out everything that is constant, obtaining
$$
\tau\cdot\frac XN\cdot g\left(\frac X{\tau N}\right)\sum_{k=1}^N(N-k).$$
What remains in the summation can be written out (in reversed order) as $$0+1+2+\cdots+(N-1)={(N-1)N\over 2},$$
using [the formula for the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers](http://www.9math.com/book/sum-first-n-natural-numbers). Putting everything together and simplifying, you'll get point 1.

For equation 2, keep in mind that $n_k$ is free of $k$ so you're summing $N$ copies of the same thing in each of the summations.